# How to apply condition in angularjs at html side?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am getting data in `{{insuredProfile.mailingAddress.isScrubbed}}` either `true` or `false`.I want to convert `true` to yes and and `false` to No. I can do this at service side but I want to know is there any way to apply this condition at `HTML` side.

My code is :

```
<li><strong>Scrub:</strong> {{insuredProfile.mailingAddress.isScrubbed}}</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this simple filter to do the same:

```
//converts truthly values to yes, others to no
.filter('yesOrNo',function() {
    return function(val) {
        if(!!val === true) {
            return 'Yes';
        }
        else {
            return 'No';
        }
    }
})
```

markup

```
<li><strong>Scrub:</strong> {{insuredProfile.mailingAddress.isScrubbed | yesOrNo}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a filter function if you find yourself doing this sort of thing throughout your applicatuib, see

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

In which case you would just pipe your expression into the filter like so:

```
<li><strong>Scrub:</strong> {{insuredProfile.mailingAddress.isScrubbed | yesNoify}}</li>
```

If it's just a one off, you could just but a function on the controllers scope and call it like so:

```
<li><strong>Scrub:</strong> {{yesNoify(insuredProfile.mailingAddress.isScrubbed)}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just using a `ng-show` statement:

```
<li><strong>Scrub:</strong>
    <span ng-show="insuredProfile.mailingAddress.isScrubbed">Yes</span>
    <span ng-show="!insuredProfile.mailingAddress.isScrubbed">No</span>
</li>
```